# Regex, convert html string to array, issue with languages and and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not an expert with regex, and have an issue trying to convert a html string to an array of html elements, so the idea was if we get by example:

Sample String:

```
<p>Welcome to my awesome website for more info <a href="www.myanotherawesomewebsite.com" target="_blank">click here</a></p>
```

(which actually can be any possible combination)

So I wanted to get something like :

```
'<p>', 'Welcome to my awesome website for more info','<a href="www.myanotherawesomewebsite.com" target="_blank">', 'click here','</a>',</p>'
```

So this could be achieved with the next regex:

```
/(<[^>]+>|[a-zè A-Z0-9]+)?/g
```

So using match function, for testing:

```
 '<p>Welcome to my awesome website for more info <a href="www.myanotherawesomewebsite.com" target="_blank">click here</a></p>'.match(/(<[^>]+>|[a-zè A-Z0-9]+)?/g)
```

and this one works, however there is a problem going on with the languages, for everything apart english works okay, but when I have characters in french, or german, this doesn't work anymore...

The work around was to do something like:

```
/(<[^>]+>|[a-zàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçäöüÄÖÜÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇß!#.?”“«» A-Z0-9\-\u00A0]+)?/g
```

which works but not 100%, also, not working at all with things like 'sup'  or 'sub', etc...

so my question is... there is a way to improve this? Help and advices will be very welcome. Thank you in advance for reading...

Comment: do you need to do this with regex? do you have access to the DOM?

Comment: [TreeWalker](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/treewalker.shtml) looks interesting. If you don't have access to the DOM, [DOMParser.parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) can make one from the string of HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `[^<]` for the non-tag node instead of enumeration of characters.
Also, I don't think you need question mark at the end. It would help only if you had an empty string input.

So the result regexp is `/(<[^>]+>|[^<]+)/g`

Comment: thank you for the answer, and yeah u were right, about the end character, so thank you for the hint, I have a question. I tested this solution and it works, however, by example in French, I am having issues with the "apostrophe". Can be done this with regular expression, or do I need to do a special replacement before, the string is coming from an API call so...cannot access manually. Thank you again

Comment: Could you paste an example, please? I could not reproduce.

Comment: Hi Nikita, I think I can handle it, looks awesome, just found one weird  thing, if I have the class attribute, it breaks, test example---->   let test = '<p class="one-class second-class">Welcome to my awesome website for more info <a href="www.myanotherawesomewebsite.com" target="_blank">click here</a></p>'
      .match(/(<[^>]+>|[^<]+)/g)
    console.log(test);

Comment: That is strange. For me it works OK with the classes - the first element is `"<p class=\"one-class second-class\">"`, second is `"Welcome to my awesome website for more info "` and so on. Should it be something else?

Comment: Hi Nikita, sorry for the late reply, yeah that might work, if I would have manually easy access to the value, but in this case implies to make a "pre-work" on the response coming from the API, so I can do a type of 'replace', which is okay :), I just wanted to know if it was possible without, anyways many many thanks for ur help, save the day!